# CSV import in neo4j using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

I'm trying to import `csv` file into `neo4j` using node.js. I have to insert data into multiple `collection/table`, so I have to insert data using node.js script. But my problem is, I can't prevent data duplication when inserting csv data.

Sample CSV data:

```
name
-------------
Afghanistan
Afghanistan
Aland
Albania
Albania
Bangladesh
Bangladesh
```

**index.js**

```
cp = require('child_process');
child = cp.fork(__dirname + "/background-import-csv-file.js");
child.on('message', function(msg) {
    console.log("background-insert-process said : ", msg);
});
file = path.resolve(__dirname, `./file/simplemaps.csv`);
child.send(file);
```

In `background-import-csv-file.js`, I have write code in two different way.

**First Promise based** (`background-import-csv-file.js`) :

```
cp = require('child_process');
csv = require('fast-csv');
Q = require('q');
DB = require("./common/driver");
Country = require('./collection/country');
process.on("message", (file) => {
  stream = fs.createReadStream(file);
  csv
    .fromStream(stream, { headers: true })
    .on("data", function(data) {
        let countryData = { "name": data.name };
        neo = new DB();
        country = new Country(neo);
        country.insert(countryData)
            .then(resp => process.send(resp.msg) )
            .catch(err => process.send(err) )
    })
     .on("end", () => process.send("file read complete") );
});
```

`./collection/country.js`:

```
  Q = require('q');
  Country = function Country(neo) {
    this.country = "Country";  this.neo = neo;
  };

  Country.prototype.find = function find(filters) {
     query = `MATCH (a:Country  { name: '${filters.name}' } )  RETURN {country:properties(a)}`;
     return this.neo.run(query, filters).then(resp => resp);
  }

  Country.prototype.create = function create(data) {
    query = `CREATE (ax:Country  { name: '${data.name}' } )  RETURN ax `;
    return this.neo.run(query, {}).then(resp => resp[0].properties).catch(err => err)
   }

   Country.prototype.insert = function insert(country) {
      filter = { name: country.name };
      return Q(this.find(filter))
        .then(resp => resp.length > 0 ? Q.resolve({ msg: `country: [${country.name}] is already exist` }) : Q.resolve(this.create(country))  )
    .then(resp => resp)
    .catch(e => Q.reject(e));
   }

   module.exports = Country;
```

`./common/driver.js`

```
neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
function DB() {
   this.driver = neo4j.driver();   this.session = this.driver.session();
}

DB.prototype.run = function run(query, data) {
    return this.session.run(query, data)
    .then(response => response.records.map(
            record => record._fields[0] ?
            record._fields.length ? record._fields[0] : {} : {}
        ) ).catch(err => new Error(err) );
}

module.exports = DB;
```

When I run `index.js` in terminal, In database, I have 2 `Afghanistan`, 1 `Aland`, 2 `Albania` and 2 `Bangladesh`. But I need  1 `Afghanistan`, 1 `Aland`, 1 `Albania` and 1 `Bangladesh` in my database. When I analyze code, than found that before inserting data, I'm checking data ( `Country.prototype.find = function find(filters)`) if it is already exist or not, but it always return empty result. That why it insert multiple data. If I run `index.js` again, then no new data is inserted into database. To solve this problem, I've tried following `CQL` :

```
  MERGE (c:Country  { name: '${data.name}' } )  RETURN c
```

It is inserted unique data, but It kill so much time. Then I have written the following  code:

**Event-driven** (`background-import-csv-file.js`) :

```
process.on("message", (file) => {
  stream = fs.createReadStream(file);
  csv
    .fromStream(stream, { headers: true })
    .on("data", function(data) {
        countryData = { "name": data.name };
        neo = new DB();
        country = new Country(neo);
        country.find(countryData);
        country.on('find', resp =>  resp.length > 0 ? Q.resolve({ msg: `country: [${country.name}] is already exist` }) : Q.resolve(country.create(countryData))  );

        country.on('create', resp => console.log(resp) );
    })
    .on("end", () => process.send("file read complete") );
});
```

`./collection/country.js`:

```
 EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
 util = require('util');

 Country = function Country(neo) {
   this.neo = neo;  EventEmitter.call(this);
 };
 util.inherits(Country, EventEmitter);

 Country.prototype.find = function find(filters) {
    query = `MATCH (a:Country  { name: '${filters.name}' } )  RETURN {country:properties(a)}`;
    return this.neo.run(query, {}).then(resp => this.emit('find', resp));
 }

 Country.prototype.create = function create(data) {
    query = `CREATE (ax:Country  { name: '${data.name}' } )  RETURN ax `;
    return this.neo.run(query, {}).then(resp => this.emit('create', resp[0].properties)).catch(err =>  err)
 }
```

And this time, it shows same result. What am I missing? Any suggestion will be very helpfull.

NB: I'm using `fast-csv` for csv parsing and `Q` for promise.

Comment: What does "lebel" mean? I do not see an obvious reason why this cannot be done with a single simple Cypher query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was, in `csv` file parsing, it was so fast (event-driven) it wasn't wait to finish insert data into database. So I have to pause file parsing and then resume it.

I solve my problem using the following code:

**Promise based (background-import-csv-file.js) :**

```
cp = require('child_process');
csv = require('fast-csv');
Q = require('q');
DB = require("./common/driver");
Country = require('./collection/country');

process.on("message", (file) => {
  stream = fs.createReadStream(file);
  csvstream = csv
    .fromStream(stream, { headers: true })
    .on("data", function(data) {
       csvstream.pause();  // pause the csv file parsing
       countryData = { "name": data.name };
       neo = new DB();
       country = new Country(neo);
       country.insert(countryData)
         .then(resp => {
             process.send(resp.msg);
             neo.close();
             return csvstream.resume(); // after completing db process, resume 
         })
         .catch(err => {
             process.send(err);
             return csvstream.resume();  // if failed, then resume 
          });
    })
    .on("end", () => process.send("file read complete") );
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I can imagine the following solutions:

1. Modify the CSV file itself with programming language(like node.js) to remove the duplicate lines with the same name.
2. Add the neo4j [unique constrains](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/constraints/#constraints-create-uniqueness-constraint)
   `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:Country) ASSERT c.name IS UNIQUE`
3. Involve the middleware, like a queue which to prevent the duplicate items, for this, you need to define you own message structure and duplicate arithmetic.

above.